# Rails - How do you display data from the devise Users table in the View files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to display a simple welcome message to the user when they log in such as,  "Welcome, Anthony!".

I created first_name and last_name attributes on the sign up and migrated them to the devise Users table and permitted the new attributes through the ApplicationController with this code,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:username, :first_name, :last_name])
  end


end
```

This works perfectly fine, however, I want to display the `first_name` in my navbar in the `application.html.erb` file, which acts as a welcome message to the user once theyve signed in.

How do I display info from the Devise Users table?

Thanks,

Ant.

(If I need to add anything else then just let me know!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you logged in you should be able to access a **current_user** object, from which you can get **first_name** and display in the welcome message in the application layout.

Comment: Thanks! current_user is what i was missing. Im new to rails! This was my solution, <% if user_signed_in? %><li>Welcome, <%= current_user.first_name %></li><% end %>